# unable to show a knob pie chart inside my page, the pie chart is now showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, pie-chart, jquery-knob

I want to add a count down pie charts inside our web page,and the pie charts will show the renaming time for our projects in the following format:-

```
**Project A**
starts in 3 weeks and 3 days

**Project B**
starts in 1 month and 2 weeks
```

here is the JavaSscript to implement this functionality and to show the above result:-

```
<script src="/Resources/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () { 
var htmlinit = "";
htmlinit = "<image  id= 'customloader' src= '/resources/ajax-loader.gif'></image>";
$("#inserhere").after(htmlinit);
var html="<div class='ms-comm-adminLinks ms-core-defaultFont ms-noList' unselectable='on'><div class='ms-webpart-titleText' unselectable='on'><a style='color:white' href='/Lists/Counter/AllItems.aspx'> Useful Links </a> </div><ul class='ms-comm-adminLinksList' unselectable='on'>";

$.ajax({
     url: "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Counter')/items?$select=Title,CounterStartDate&$orderby=CounterStartDate asc",
     method: "GET",   
     headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
     success: function (data) {
        if(data.d.results.length>0){

            var items=data.d.results;
            for(var i=0;i<items.length;i++){        
                    var nurl = items[i].CounterStartDate.toString();
                    var ntitle = items[i].Title.toString();
                    var loopidcustom = "demo"+i.toString();


    var formatteddate = datediff(new Date (nurl));
    document.getElementById(loopidcustom).innerHTML = "<b>" + ntitle + "</b><br> Start Date "+ d+"<br/> Starts in  " + formatteddate +"<hr/>"  ;

    if (distance < 0) {
        //clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById(loopidcustom).innerHTML = "";
    }




      }

        }
     },
     error: function (data) {   
     $("#customloader").hide();
     }
    });




});

function datediff(date) {
   let d1 = date;
   let d2 = now = new Date();
   if (d2.getTime() < d1.getTime()) {
     d1 = now;
     d2 = date;
   }
   let yd = d1.getYear();
   let yn = d2.getYear();
   let years = yn - yd;
   let md = d1.getMonth();
   let mn = d2.getMonth();
   let months = mn - md;
   if (months < 0) {
     years--;
     months = 12 - md + mn;
   }
   let dd = d1.getDate();
   let dn = d2.getDate();
   let days = dn - dd;
   if (days < 0) {
     months--;
     // figure out how many days there are in the last month
     d2.setMonth(mn, 0);
     days = d2.getDate() - dd + dn;
   }
   let weeks = Math.floor(days / 7);
   days = days % 7;
   if (years > 0) return years + ' years' + (months > 0 ? ' and ' + months + ' months' : '');
   if (months > 0) return months + ' months' + (weeks > 0 ? ' and ' + weeks + ' weeks' : '');
   if (weeks > 0) return weeks + ' weeks' + (days > 0 ? ' and ' + days + ' days' : '');
   return days + ' days';
}
</script>
```

now i want to modifiy this and to show the remaining Year,Month,Week and Days inside pie charts,instead of only showing text. so i find this Read-Only knob pie chart interesting http://anthonyterrien.com/demo/knob/
:-

[image]

but i am facing these issues, when i try to test it inside our web page:-

1. i added the following code to test how the pie chart will look like:-

   ```
   <script>
       $(function($) {

           $(".knob").knob({
               change : function (value) {
                   //console.log("change : " + value);
               },
               release : function (value) {
                   //console.log(this.$.attr('value'));
                   console.log("release : " + value);
               },
               cancel : function () {
                   console.log("cancel : ", this);
               },
               /*format : function (value) {
                return value + '%';
                },*/
               draw : function () {

                   // "tron" case
                   if(this.$.data('skin') == 'tron') {

                       this.cursorExt = 0.3;

                       var a = this.arc(this.cv)  // Arc
                               , pa                   // Previous arc
                               , r = 1;

                       this.g.lineWidth = this.lineWidth;

                       if (this.o.displayPrevious) {
                           pa = this.arc(this.v);
                           this.g.beginPath();
                           this.g.strokeStyle = this.pColor;
                           this.g.arc(this.xy, this.xy, this.radius - this.lineWidth, pa.s, pa.e, pa.d);
                           this.g.stroke();
                       }

                       this.g.beginPath();
                       this.g.strokeStyle = r ? this.o.fgColor : this.fgColor ;
                       this.g.arc(this.xy, this.xy, this.radius - this.lineWidth, a.s, a.e, a.d);
                       this.g.stroke();

                       this.g.lineWidth = 2;
                       this.g.beginPath();
                       this.g.strokeStyle = this.o.fgColor;
                       this.g.arc( this.xy, this.xy, this.radius - this.lineWidth + 1 + this.lineWidth * 2 / 3, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
                       this.g.stroke();

                       return false;
                   }
               }
           });

           // Example of infinite knob, iPod click wheel
           var v, up=0,down=0,i=0
                   ,$idir = $("div.idir")
                   ,$ival = $("div.ival")
                   ,incr = function() { i++; $idir.show().html("+").fadeOut(); $ival.html(i); }
                   ,decr = function() { i--; $idir.show().html("-").fadeOut(); $ival.html(i); };
           $("input.infinite").knob(
                   {
                       min : 0
                       , max : 20
                       , stopper : false
                       , change : function () {
                       if(v > this.cv){
                           if(up){
                               decr();
                               up=0;
                           }else{up=1;down=0;}
                       } else {
                           if(v < this.cv){
                               if(down){
                                   incr();
                                   down=0;
                               }else{down=1;up=0;}
                           }
                       }
                       v = this.cv;
                   }
                   });
       });
   </script>
   <style>
       body{

           font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
           font-weight: 300;
           text-rendering: optimizelegibility;
       }
       p{font-size: 30px; line-height: 30px}
       div.demo{text-align: center; width: 280px; float: left}
       div.demo > p{font-size: 20px}
   </style>
   ```

but i got only the number  without any pie chart around it as follow:-

[image]

2. Second question, now let say i manage to show the pie chart correctly. then can i modify the way the pie charts are being constructed? for example in my case i want the pie charts to show count downs, so if the remaining is 1-Day then the pie chart should be almost fully colored. and i will have those different ranges:-

   - for Day it can be from 1 to 7
   - for month it can be from 1 to 12
   - for weeks it can be from 1 to 4

so is this possible ?

Comment: You can try the [roundSlider](http://roundsliderui.com) plugin which can be customize-able in any way. Check the below demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/soundar24/LpuLe9tr/289/

Is this similar to your requirement, or do you need any other customization?

Comment: @Soundar will try it looks great, although in my case i need to show the counters in Years,Month, Weeks and days.. and no need for timer..  my `datediff` function will return a string as follow `1 week and 3 days` or `4 months and 3 weeks`. so i will need to split the text between the word `and` ,, and then build the charts

Comment: is my below answer solves your requirement?

Answer (score 1):

@john, based on your comments I have prepared a sample using [**roundSlider**](http://roundsliderui.com) plugin. Check the below demo and let me know whether it satisfies your requirement:

## [`DEMO`](http://jsfiddle.net/soundar24/u1p6qLgL/)

Here due to the sample purpose I used the hard-coded id, you can change this as based on your application scenario.